# Static view holder vs Adapter reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have recycler view adapter and I keep the id of selected view holder in the adapter and to access the selection field I have two options : 
1- make view holder class not status which I read it's bad 
2- add a reference for the adapter in the view holder

what should I do for better memory performance and why?

Comment: Why you need keep reference adapter in holder. I think you should pass only selected id in onBindViewHolder no need keep reference to adapter

Comment: I'm changing its value when item view is clicked

Comment: When you changing value you should call callback I mean adapter will be set callback when init holder everytime click callback should call and adapter can updated selected id by adapterPosition

Comment: You mean none of the ways is good and I should use interface for passing data between adapter and viewholder?

Comment: Yes correct. 1 defined interface OnItemListener with method onSelectIdChaned(pos) 2. implemens it in adapter. 3 pass interface when onCreateViewHolder, find view and set events for view 3. When on onSelectIdChaned(pos) trigger should update your list by pos dont forget call notifyAdapterChange or you can notifyItemChange to change UI

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the ViewHolder the data itself. Let's say you have a recycler view that displays a list of User's data, you can add to the ViewHolder the field user (ie `var user: User? = null`), and then when you bind the view holder you can set the value (ie `holder.user = list.get(position)` ). Then when you click on a button you can access that member.

Comment: I need a selected field to hold the position of the selected view holder

Comment: So add in the holder a var position: Int and fill it inside onBind